# Failed build flutter apk file in android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in flutter , I'm using android studio to create my flutter app and I have done my app!

My app is running without problem on simulator,I need upload my app to google play & app store, when I build the app for app bundle it's work but when I build for apk I get an error !

This is the error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 1m 47s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          108.1s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to 
try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                     
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Surely I have created my app for AndroidX, so my app contain AndroidX already (gradle.properties) file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I'm trying to create new project and move my lib file and pubspec.yaml file but I encountered same problem.

my pubspec.yaml file:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: 0.15.3
  firebase_storage: 3.1.1
  cloud_firestore: 0.13.4
  shared_preferences: 0.5.4+6
  flutter_offline: 0.3.0
  provider: 3.1.0
  simple_animations: ^1.1.3
  page_transition: 1.1.4
  cupertino_icons: 0.1.3
  gradient_app_bar: 0.0.1
  fluttertoast: 3.1.1
  flutter_spinkit: 4.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: 0.7.3
  rflutter_alert: 1.0.3
  url_launcher: 4.1.0
  flutter_speed_dial: 1.2.5
  image_picker: 0.6.2
  file_picker: 1.4.3+2
  validators: 2.0.0+1
  dio: 3.0.8
  flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer: 1.0.7

dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: 0.4.4
```

Comment: The project that throws AndroidX incompatibility is cloud_firestore not yours. Did you setup the package as it described?  if yes, try to clean and rebuild or see the gradle version that used in the example of cloud_firestore package and use the same on yours

Comment: @HamedHamedi  I don't know what did you mean (setup the package as it described?) In addtion, my gradle version is 3.5.0

Comment: I mean the Android section of this link https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore